# compilation error when installing Monero, unable to recognise boost version

Tags: boost, cmake

I am trying to install Monero on Ubuntu 16.04 however I get an error on make. libboost-all-dev (>=1.58) however the current version is 1.58, can anyone explain why this is happening

```
-- Using C security hardening flags:  -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-protector -fstack-protector-strong -mmitigate-rop
-- Using C++ security hardening flags:  -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-protector -fstack-protector-strong -mmitigate-rop
-- Using linker security hardening flags:  -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,noexecstack
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1677 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.55.0

  Boost include path: /usr/local/include

  Detected version of Boost is too old.  Requested version was 1.58 (or
  newer).
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:929 (find_package)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:105 (message):
  Could not find Boost libraries, please make sure you have installed
  Boost or libboost-all-dev (>=1.58) or the equivalent
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:933 (die)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/azureuser/monero/build/Linux/master/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/azureuser/monero/build/Linux/master/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'release-all' failed
make: *** [release-all] Error 1
```

Comment: "however the current version is 1.58" - Does this mean that you have Boost 1.58 to be installed? How have you installed it?

Comment: I installed with sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

Comment: The package `libboost-all-dev` installs Boost under `/usr`, but CMake founds Boost under `/usr/local`. It seems you have **another** Boost installation which confuses CMake. The simples way would be to delete old Boost installation. Alternatively, you could give a hint to CMake to prefer 1.58 installation to another one. E.g. by setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to `/usr`. (Do not forget to remove your build directory before new attempt).